# How to change presence of selfbot

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to change the presence of self bots by sending a command to the chat (e.g. !setstatus idle), but I am unsure what to set x.change_presence to, other than it should be a bot object.

> Cog File (/discord bot/cogs/Bots.py)

```
class Bots(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
        @commands.command()
        async def setstatus(self, ctx, status='online'):
             print('Changing Status')

                if status.lower() == 'online':
                    await ctx.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
             
                elif status.lower() == 'idle'
                    await ctx.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
```

> Main Script (/discord bot/main.py)

```
for i in range(len(tokens)):

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',self_bot=False)
    loop.create_task(bot.start(tokens[i], bot=False))
    
    extensions = ['cogs.Bots']

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for extension in extensions:
            bot.load_extension(extension)

loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Just so you know selfbots are against the discord TOS and you can get your account banned

Comment: @blu Can we not make stackoverflow articles about the TOS but instead just strictly talk code on here? I am extremely aware of discords TOS and have been reminded multiple times on other posts of mine and other articles I have read.

Answer (score 0):

The command would be an instance of your bot.

```
self.bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle)
```

Comment: I receive the error ```NameError: name 'bot' is not defined```.

Comment: @exe try self.bot.change_presence

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy.
You have the wrong intend in your cog!

You need to

```py
class Bots(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command()
    async def setstatus(self, ctx, status="online"):
        print('Changing Status')

        if status.lower() == "online":
            await self.bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
             
        elif status.lower() == "idle":
            await self.bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
```

Because the commands and events cames under the `def __init__(self, bot)`.
Thats one of the basics.

And you need to use `await self.bot.change_presence()` instead of `await ctx.change_presence()`